# Why does the below Perl code show "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string" when I try to use the command opendir

Tags: perl

I was writing code to display all the files and subfolders in a directory.
Is `opendir` and `readdir` only used to display files or can it display subdirectories as well?

Following is the code I am using, i don't know what I should try instead.

```
#!/apps/perl/5.8.9/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

opendir DIR , "/home/x0280511/" || die;
while (readdir DIR) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

I am getting the following error message

> Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string

What exactly does the above error message mean?

Comment: Having the main thing fixed by `mwp`, also note: (1) Need to use `or` for error checking above, not `||` (2) print [`$!` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) which has the actual reason for the error (3) Use "lexical filehandle" (look it up).  So: `opendir my $dfh, $dirname  or die "Can't open $dirname: $!";`

Comment: The `||` [operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) "binds" too tightly for the above use: it evaluates `"/home/..." || die` first, and since the string `"/home/..."` is indeed "true" it opens the directory, and if that fails it won't go to `die` anymore.  But if you use `or` (Instead of `||`) then you get `(open my $dfh, $dir)  or (die ...)` -- so now it checks whether `open` works first, and if it didn't it goes to `die`.

Comment: To specifically answer the question: "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string" is a warning, not an error, and it's emitted by interpolating (concatenating) `$_` into `"$_\n"` because `$_` has not been set to a defined value.

Answer (score 2):

A bare `readdir` is only valid in a while-loop expression on Perl 5.12+. If you're on an earlier version of Perl, you'll need to use a different syntax to force scalar context:

```perl
while (my $ent = readdir DIR) {
  print "$ent\n";
}
```

Or you can use `readdir` in list context, just note that it will query the entire directory contents before displaying the first entry:

```perl
foreach my $ent (readdir DIR) {
  print "$ent\n";
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you.
1st method helped to generate output

Comment: I'd also recommend either of these methods in general instead of relying on bare readdir in while - not only does it use the global `$_` which can be affected by anything you call, it doesn't localize it, similar to the bare while-readline construct.